# Looking for a 80's movie where a man jumps on a desert train

Tags: story-identification, tv

The film starts in a desert and a man is there. This sci fi train goes through the desert, while the man jumps on and fights some badies I think; he ends up in city, rescues the princess etc

Saw it on TV a few times years ago probably 80`s mad max style

Comment: So, not Mad Max? Then probably Mad Max II or Mad Max III...

Comment: Seriously now, we do need some more info to narrow this down. What was sci-fi-ish about the train? Do you remember anything about the "etc" part?

Comment: Possibly `Wild Wild West`. Either the Will Smith version or the classic. Both had something like this I believe.

Comment: You sure it was a sci-fi train? Definitely not a rom-com minivan?

Comment: I seem to remember a film with a big trailer truck, and the girl to be rescued turned out to be the daughter of the bad guy. Can't seem to find it though.

Comment: even though i am sure it was not mad max i am going to watch all three again just to see(its been a long time). there was definately a train at the begining covered in random metal bits and it was in a desert, but that doesnt narrow it down any.

Answer (score 3):

[*Survivor* (1987)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0204661/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_127) is a post-apocalyptic film starring Christopher Mayer as The Survivor, an astronaut who is walking through the desert, seeking an underground city with abundant supplies. He rescues a female prisoner who may know of the location of this city, but she's captured by Kragg, a bandit, so he has to rescue her. In the process, he finds the underground city, a buried power station, and is tasked by the survivors there to kill Kragg. [This review](http://www.cultreviews.com/reviews/survivor/) covers more of the plot details.

Trailer:

Comment: No mention of trains in the reviews I've found...

Comment: It was a solar-powered handcar that exploded on impact at the end of the line.

Comment: Ah. That makes more sense.